# Was Suzanne Coleman killed when she was 7 months pregnant with Bill Clinton's child?

Tags: united-states, bill-clinton

Are these statements true about Suzanne Coleman found on Twitter? I tried searching her name, but nearly all results were about 'Clinton Body Counts'. She doesn't have a Wikipedia page.

[image: Suzanne Coleman]

Comment: The story has the typical style of a bad conspiracy theory: the Powers are extremely powerful and extremely incompetent at the same time. It is implied that Clinton hired an assassin to kill Coleman and make it look like a suicide; the assassin then chose to shoot her on the back of the head; the Powers then prevented the autopsy (which would have, what, determined that her elbow does not bend backwards?)...

Comment: As a passing comment, I have found that all of these "I'm so-and-so and A CLINTON DID SOMETHING BAD TO ME" are sketchy at best.

Comment: The originator of the graphic didn't even take the trouble to spell her name right.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/politics/clintons/bodycount.asp) mentions this as part of its FALSE "Clinton Body Bags" page:

> *15. Suzane Coleman — reportedly had an affair with Clinton. Was seven months pregnant at the time she was found dead of a gun shot wound to the back of the head, ruled suicide.*
>
> At the time of Susan Coleman’s suicide, Bill Clinton was her law
>   professor. In 1992 an overzealous supporter of George Bush hired
>   investigators to probe this girl’s 1977 suicide, and they found no
>   evidence that she and Clinton had an affair. It was an old rumor and a
>   baseless one, and even a determined attempt at muckraking turned up
>   nothing to substantiate it.

There is an [anti-Clinton site claiming to be the Clinton Memorial Library](http://www.clintonmemoriallibrary.com/body-count/clinton-casualties/) (the [real library site](https://www.clintonlibrary.gov/) is very different) which says

> Suzanne Coleman had an affair with Bill Clinton when he was Attorney
>   General in Arkansas. On 15 February 1977, she “committed suicide” with
>   a gunshot to the back of the head. No autopsy was performed, but it
>   has been alleged that she was seven-and-a-half months pregnant with
>   Clinton’s child, although never proven.

So your claim is true to the extent that Suzanne Coleman's death was ruled a suicide.  There does not seem to any evidence for the affair or pregnancy claims; if there had been then both these quotes would have said more

Comment: Was she shot in the back of the head? That seems to be clear-cut to fact check.

Comment: The Snopes article provides a list of sources, but it doesn't attribute each claim to a source, so it is very difficult to see how they drew the conclusion that there was no evidence and the rumour was baseless.

Comment: Dear commenters: Note that I criticised the Snopes source, without having to resort to a political attack suggesting they were wrong, just because I my perceived view of their partisanship. Please remember we are not interesting in your political opinions.

Comment: @Oddthinking I think you're applying way too high a standard for Snopes on this: There's no evidence in the original claims to support the allegation. It's one thing to suggest that a claim is not true; it's another to point out that people have looked into this, and that there's not even a rationale provided to support the claim being made.

Comment: @Jeffronicus: Who looked into this? Where do those people say there is no evidence? I want to see that for myself,  but Snopes have made that a very expensive effort - I have to read several books looking for it.

Comment: Here's a 1992 UPI story about the Bush campaign distancing itself from Floyd Brown, who was fluffing the story: https://www.upi.com/Archives/1992/07/15/Bush-files-FEC-complaint-against-Willie-Horton-creator/5511711172800/: "The network said [Brown's] committee seized an anonymous letter mass mailed to news organizations alleging that Susan Coleman's 1977 suicide followed a love affair with her law professor, Bill Clinton, that left her pregnant. CBS said Coleman's family maintained there was no truth to this, and said reporters who had investigated the letter found it to be a nasty hoax."

Comment: Ironically, it's the pushing of claims like these, non-stop, that probably led to possibly legitimate claims (Juanita Broddrick?) being dismissed out of hand.